# An unexpected error occurred while upload app bundle on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I am trying to push an update of my app on play store. Everytime I upload app bundle, it gives me error i.e "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (53F0C748)
[image]

Any solutions???

Comment: Try with classic Play Console

Comment: That is no more accessible, it is giving 403

Comment: Only Play Developer support can help you.

Comment: I submitted ticket twice, no response

Comment: Did you reach out by email or chat? Or where did you submit a ticket?

Comment: I submitted ticket at google developer support